# How can I use Tabnine in a DevContainer?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, tabnine

I've been regularly using the Tabnine VSCode extension on my computer for a while now, and it's been very helpful so far. However, I'm having trouble installing it inside a DevContainer.

[Outside the DevContainer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXMWA.png), Tabnine works perfectly fine.
On the other hand, although I've installed Tabnine as an extension in the DevContainer, [inside the DevContainer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJviy.png)
there are no suggestions being made, typing `tabnine::config` does nothing, and there's no TabNine icon in the Activity Bar.

I've tried adding port forwarding to port 5555, but VSCode automatically changes it to port 5556, and it doesn't fix the issue.

Is there anything I can do to get TabNine working in my DevContainer? I'm still very much a beginner, so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using M1 chip then try to force build docker image with flag "--platform linux/amd64". Tabnine will run just fine

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install `Tabnine` extension in the devcontainer. Only install it in the Host instance and the `devcontainer` will auto do the port forwarding for you.

Tested with version of `Tabnine v3.5.45`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm not sure what you mean by "Windows instance"—could you please add a screenshot? I'm using `Tabnine v3.5.45` too, but I'm still having trouble getting it to work in my `devcontainer`, even after uninstalling it from the `devcontainer`.

Comment: @AnoopR Are you using WSL2 or Linux or Mac?

Comment: I'm using a Mac (MacOS Big Sur v11.6), and I'm having the same issue even in the [sample Python devcontainer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-try-python) that VSCode provides.

Comment: @AnoopR try not to install the tabnine extension in devcontainer and only install it in the host machine ( Mac). The devcontainer should auto forward the port for the tabnine extension